# What happens when a bounded vec in storage is fully populated and then its bound is reduced?

Tags: boundedvec

Consider the following scenario, where I have a `BoundedVec` which has bound parameter `MaxItems`. Now this `MaxItems` parameter would be configured in the runtime.

```
pub type StorageItem<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> =
        StorageValue<_, BoundedVec<Id, T::MaxItems>, ValueQuery>;
```

Let's say that `MaxItems` was set to `10`. And during the course of the operation of the chain the BoundedVec `StorageItem` is (fully) populated with `10` items.

If in a runtime upgrade I reduce this `MaxItems` value in the runtime to `5` (5 < 10). Will my `StorageItem` refuse to decode perhaps with a panic? Or will it just decode the first 5 that it finds...

What would be the behavior here? And how about similar bounded structs such as BoundedBtreeMap and BoundedBtreeSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question!

Just reducing the bound will indeed result in a decoding error. It will behave like any other decode error; not panic but either return `None` or `Default` depending on whether you are using `OptionQuery` or `ValueQuery`.
If you want to properly reduce the bound, you have to truncate the vector in a migration to ensure that it will fit into the new bound. `BoundedBtreeMap` and `BoundedBtreeSet` behave likewise.
There also is `WeakBoundedVec`, but that is of limited usefulness for cases where you are unsure about the bound, since it will decode anyway.

The reason to have `BoundedVec` in the first place is to know how much data we have to read from storage in the worst case.
The worst-case of `BoundedVec<T, L>` would be about `T::max_encoded_len() * L::get()` (excluding its prefixed length).  This is important to calculate pre-dispatch PoV weights (chromatic weights, aka Weights V2).
Now currently the logic for reading a `BoundedVec` does actually not enforce it, since it first decodes and then throws the vector away if it is too long. It would be better to only read the length first and check.
Anyway, in short; It can be used to restrict some theoretical worst cases since `Vec` *could* have up to `usize::MAX` elements.
So for now it probably does not make much difference if you use `Weak` or not, since `Weak` and `Bounded` both don't *really* enforce the worst case, but in the future `Bounded` hopefully will.
IMHO it is just better practice to use `Bounded`, but I see that it very dangerous in some cases and requires much attention not to brick a chain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I have two more questions:
1. "... but that is of limited usefulness for cases where you are unsure about the bound, since it will decode anyway." But this sounds very useful for when we do not know what the bound will be in the future, right? Because then persistent data can still be accessed.
2. Is there a problem with using `WeakBoundedVec` everywhere instead of `BoundedVec`? Sounds like a nice hack to prevent storage dependent logic from breaking if we forget to perform a storage migration when we decrease the bound.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! @Oliver Tale-Yazdi